# Multiple dhcp servers on separate lans connected to same modem - is it possible?

Tags: dhcp

I have 2 clients who share a cable connection that has a modem/router on it. I call this one lan 0, which has dhcp disabled. There are two Cisco/Linksys routers attached to lan0, named Lan1 and Lan 2, with fixed ip addresses in the 0 range and which use the lan0 router as their internet gateway. The routers on lans 1 and 2 function as access points for their respective lans. All the desktop computers and network printers on lan1 have fixed ip addresses in the 192.168.1.10-50 range, while the equipment hardwired to lan2 have fixed ip addresses in the 192.168.2.10-50 range.

This all works fine until we introduce wireless connections with dhcp on lans1 and 2. What is happening is that a wireless connection to lan2's ssid will end up picking up a lan1 ip address.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

The two LANs should have no access to each other whatsoever, so the incorrect IPs must be being generated by the router that is local to that LAN.

I think you probably have a misconfiguration in the DHCP settings on the router.